# Как получить доступ к "стандартному" заголовку в toolbar'e?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Делаю программу на основе гугловского шаблона из АндроидСтудии. Нужно модифицировать заголовок в туллбаре (конкретно: сделать паддинг, выровнять по центру). Как можно получить к нему доступ? Где искать?

Comment: может скриншот приложите хотя бы ?

Comment: вы не сможете это сделать в стандартом тулбаре. вам придется в родной тулбар положить TextView и обращаться уже к нему. но мой совет - не заниматься этим. Тулбар, наверное, один из самых капризных элементов в Андроиде. или используйте родной или думайте над альтернативными вариантами.

Comment: как оказалось, действительно нельзя.... Но решение нашел. Ниже мой ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос применением к toolbar'у Material-дизайна. Там можно многое делать.